# How can I reduce the memory of a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas for my day to day work and some of the data frames I use are overwhelmingly big (in the order of hundreds of millions of rows by hundreds of columns). Is there any way of reducing the RAM memory consumption?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this function. It reduces the size of the data by clamping the data types to the minimum required for each column.

The code is not mine, I copied it from the following link and I adapted it for my needs.
https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/how-to-reduce-memory-usage-in-pandas/

```
def reduce_mem_usage(df, int_cast=True, obj_to_category=False, subset=None):
    """
    Iterate through all the columns of a dataframe and modify the data type to reduce memory usage.
    :param df: dataframe to reduce (pd.DataFrame)
    :param int_cast: indicate if columns should be tried to be casted to int (bool)
    :param obj_to_category: convert non-datetime related objects to category dtype (bool)
    :param subset: subset of columns to analyse (list)
    :return: dataset with the column dtypes adjusted (pd.DataFrame)
    """
    start_mem = df.memory_usage().sum() / 1024 ** 2;
    gc.collect()
    print('Memory usage of dataframe is {:.2f} MB'.format(start_mem))

    cols = subset if subset is not None else df.columns.tolist()

    for col in tqdm(cols):
        col_type = df[col].dtype

        if col_type != object and col_type.name != 'category' and 'datetime' not in col_type.name:
            c_min = df[col].min()
            c_max = df[col].max()

            # test if column can be converted to an integer
            treat_as_int = str(col_type)[:3] == 'int'
            if int_cast and not treat_as_int:
                treat_as_int = check_if_integer(df[col])

            if treat_as_int:
                if c_min > np.iinfo(np.int8).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int8).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int8)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.uint8).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.uint8).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.uint8)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.int16).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int16).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int16)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.uint16).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.uint16).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.uint16)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.int32).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int32).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int32)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.uint32).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.uint32).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.uint32)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.int64).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int64).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int64)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.uint64).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.uint64).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.uint64)
            else:
                if c_min > np.finfo(np.float16).min and c_max < np.finfo(np.float16).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float16)
                elif c_min > np.finfo(np.float32).min and c_max < np.finfo(np.float32).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float32)
                else:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float64)
        elif 'datetime' not in col_type.name and obj_to_category:
            df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
    gc.collect()
    end_mem = df.memory_usage().sum() / 1024 ** 2
    print('Memory usage after optimization is: {:.3f} MB'.format(end_mem))
    print('Decreased by {:.1f}%'.format(100 * (start_mem - end_mem) / start_mem))

    return df
```

Comment: This code is missing the imports (gc, tqdm) and the definition of "check_if_integer", maybe even more.

Comment: This is also inherently flawed, it completely ignores the float precision which may be (and likely is) required.

Comment: messed up the precision. The 75% memory reduction seemed nice.. Until I noticed that all of the numbers  (related to finance) are either approximated in a wrong way or bluntly having different value from the source (precision lost after some decimal). This should probably be addressed in the "accepted" answer.

Comment: Can you please give some examples and a reproducible sample to debug and under stand your concern?

Answer (score 5):

Consider using [Dask DataFrames](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) if your data does not fit memory. It has nice features like delayed computation and parallelism, which allow you to keep data on disk and pull it in a chunked way only when results are needed. It also has a pandas-like interface so you can mostly keep your current code.

Comment: Does it work well in general? I tried it like 2 years ago and it was very buggy

Comment: It works pretty well for me. But I often follow the "Reduce, and then use Pandas" suggestion here https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html , so for the more intricate parts of the analysis I may default to pandas itself.

Answer (score 2):

If are working with dataframe with numeric value you could consider using the `downcast` option of `apply`. Its not as efficient as the accepted solution (only 50% reduction) but it is more simple and faster. I do not have problems of precision loss beacuse Im converting float64 to float32 and not float16.

Here is my original dataframe memory usage :

```py
df.info(memory_usage="deep")

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 644 entries, 0 to 643
Columns: 1028 entries, 0 to 1027
dtypes: float64(1012), int64(16)
memory usage: 5.1 MB
```

Then I use the apply function :

```py
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float')
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='integer')
```

Here is modified dataframe memory usage :

```py
df.info(memory_usage="deep")

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 644 entries, 0 to 643
Columns: 1028 entries, 0 to 1027
dtypes: float32(1012), int8(16)
memory usage: 2.5 MB
```

Comment: you need to be careful as downcast sometimes can be inaccurate
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.19.0.html#downcast-values-to-smallest-possible-dtype-in-to-numeric