# Pandas - MemoryError: Unable to allocate 220. MiB

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, bigdata

So I have a data frame of orders, with the order date as the index, which I set so:

```
df = df.set_index('ORDER_ENTRY_DATE', drop=False)
```

In the code below I create a new feature, containing the total amount successfully paid in the last 8 weeks for a specific customer. (excluding current order)

```
df["LAST_8_WEEKS_SUCCESSFUL"] = (df["PAYMENT_SUCCESSFUL"].mul(df["TOTAL_AMOUNT"])
                                                                .groupby(df["CUST_NO"])
                                                                .transform(lambda x: x.rolling(window='56D', min_periods= 1).sum().shift())
                                                                .fillna(0)
                                        )
```

I have tested this code on a smaller version of my dataset and it works fine, but when running it on the full fledged 28 million rows dataset, I get a memory error

`MemoryError: Unable to allocate 220. MiB for an array with shape (28879273,) and data type int64`

Is there any other way to accomplish this without needing 220 MiB RAM? Is my code way too inefficient?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reduce the memory of a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57531388/how-can-i-reduce-the-memory-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Without more detail regarding your DF, the only thing I can advise is to pick the right datatype for each column, and use categories where possible. Use `memory_usage()` to measure the current size and the possible improvement after any modification.